# How to count the color detected objects using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, color-detection

I am trying to detect objects using color. Below is the code and the image:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('image2.jpeg')
img1 = img[157:498, 212:705]

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_bound = np.array([0, 20, 20])
upper_bound = np.array([20, 255, 255])
origMask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_bound, upper_bound)
kernel = np.ones((7, 7), np.uint8)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(origMask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("Crop Image", img1)
cv2.imshow("Orig Image", img)
    
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

So in the above code, I am loading the image first. Then cropping it to a desired area and then performing the HSV to find orange color objects.

Below is the original image:

[image]

Below is the cropped image:

[image]

Below is the mask image after hsv:

[image]

I want to know how can I count the number of objects in the mask image. For example, in this case it is 3. And after counting it, how can I draw bounding box over these color objects on the original image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your binary mask to get the **contours** of the image. Then, you can compute the **bounding rectangles** belonging to each contour. Assume the input is your binary mask, the script should look like this:

```
# imports:
import cv2

# image path
path = "D://opencvImages//"
fileName = "objectsMask.png" # This is your binary mask

# Reading an image in default mode:
inputImage = cv2.imread(path + fileName)

# Deep copy for results:
inputImageCopy = inputImage.copy()

# Convert RGB to grayscale:
grayscaleImage = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Find the contours on the binary image:
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(grayscaleImage, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Store bounding rectangles and object id here:
objectData = []

# ObjectCounter:
objectCounter = 1

# Look for the outer bounding boxes (no children):
for _, c in enumerate(contours):
    # Get the contour's bounding rectangle:
    boundRect = cv2.boundingRect(c)

    # Store in list:
    objectData.append((objectCounter, boundRect))

    # Get the dimensions of the bounding rect:
    rectX = boundRect[0]
    rectY = boundRect[1]
    rectWidth = boundRect[2]
    rectHeight = boundRect[3]

    # Draw bounding rect:
    color = (0, 0, 255)
    cv2.rectangle(inputImageCopy, (int(rectX), int(rectY)),
                  (int(rectX + rectWidth), int(rectY + rectHeight)), color, 2)

    # Draw object counter:
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    fontScale = 1
    fontThickness = 2
    color = (0, 255, 0)
    cv2.putText(inputImageCopy, str(objectCounter), (int(rectX), int(rectY)), 
                font, fontScale, color, fontThickness)

    # Increment object counter
    objectCounter += 1

    cv2.imshow("Rectangles", inputImageCopy)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I'm creating a list called `objectData`. Here, I'm storing the object's "id" (just an object counter) and its bounding rectangle. This is the output:

[image]